# passing data to Zend_Db_Table_Rowset and returning the model for each row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have an array that I cache, which was returned from a database model that extends zend_db_Table_abstract. I use ->toArray() on the object. When retrieving the data I would like to convert it back to that model.

I tried doing the following

```
$modules = new Zend_Db_Table_Rowset(array('data' => $modules, 'table' => 'modules', 'rowClass' => 'Model_Db_Module'));
```

now when I iterate.

```
foreach ($modules as $module)
    echo $module->name;
```

I get nothing! If I remove 'rowClass' => 'Model_Db_Module'. It returns the correct value. How can I go by returning the correct object so that i can manipulate the data if I need to?  If i needed to use

```
 $module->name = "Cool Stuff";
 $module->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just cache the object and call ->setTable() when retrieving cache data.